# Where is the memory leak despite following the rules?

Tags: c++, valgrind

Hey guy's i cant seem to find the memory leak even tho i deleted everything before i initialize the object array and delete it when im not using it anymore. Unfortunately valgrind doesnt tell me where the error is but it does say i have 10/11 memory leak , here is my codes below. Dont mid the repetitiveness of the to copy functions i will change that shortly.

```
// Default Constructor
Basket::Basket() {
  setEmpty();
}

// SetEmpty
void Basket::setEmpty() {
  m_fruits = nullptr;
  m_cnt = 0;
  m_price = 0;
}

// Destructor
Basket::~Basket() {
  delete[] m_fruits;
  m_fruits = nullptr;
}


// copy assignment operator
Basket & Basket::operator = (const Basket & other) {
  if (this != & other) {
    setEmpty();
    m_cnt = other.m_cnt;
    m_price = other.m_price;
    m_fruits = new Fruit[other.m_cnt];
    for (int i = 0; i < other.m_cnt; i++) {
      m_fruits[i] = other.m_fruits[i];
    }
    delete[] other.m_fruits;
  }
  return *this;
}

//set price;
void Basket::setPrice(double price) {
  m_price = price;
}
```

Comment: Please add the valgrind output also.

Comment: Do you have some code that uses this object?

Comment: Dunno if it's the cause of a memory leak, but the `delete[] other.m_fruits;` inside `operator=` is almost certainly a mistake.  The fact that `other` is marked `const` in the operator's argument is a promise to the caller that you won't change the passed-in `Basket`'s state, and deleting its contents is definitely changing its state, not to mention that it leaves it holding a dangling pointer, which is going to cause trouble.

Comment: Yeah, the copy constructor and copy assignment operator here can leave the `m_fruit` pointer dangling for the object being copied to/assigned to,

Comment: Your assignment operator leaves memory leaks, you do not free pointers before you overwrite

Comment: @SeanF i call a setEmpty function before i write it tho?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Oh yeah, i was just testing something for some reason valgrind went froom 2 block mem leak to 1, so i just left it

Comment: @Azeem all it says is i have memory leak in 2 block

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `std::vector<Fruit>` instead of `Fruit *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a leak if you do the following:

```
#include "basket.h"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char **)
{
    Fruit fruits[2] = {{"Fruit a2"}, {"Fruit b2"}};
    Basket basket2(fruits, 2, 10.0);

    Fruit a("Fruit a");
    Fruit b("Fruit b");
    Basket basket;
    basket +=a;
    basket +=b;

    basket = basket2; // errors happen here
}
```

You are setting `Basket::m_fruits` to nullptr before deleting it. You will need to change your `Basket::operator = (const Basket & other)` to:

```
Basket & Basket::operator = (const Basket & other) {
  if (this != & other) {
    if(m_fruits != nullptr) delete[] m_fruits;
    setEmpty();
    m_cnt = other.m_cnt;
    m_price = other.m_price;
    m_fruits = new Fruit[other.m_cnt];
    for (int i = 0; i < other.m_cnt; i++) {
      m_fruits[i] = other.m_fruits[i];
    }
  }
  return *this;
}
```

You also have possible invalid free/delete in your `Basket::~Basket()` if `m_fruits` is still empty. Change it to:

```
Basket::~Basket() {
  if(m_fruits != nullptr) delete[] m_fruits;
}
```

Now the following works without a problem:

```
#include "basket.h"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char **)
{
    Fruit fruits[2] = {{"Fruit a2"}, {"Fruit b2"}};
    Basket basket2(fruits, 2, 10.0);

    Fruit a("Fruit a");
    Fruit b("Fruit b");
    Basket basket;
    basket +=a;
    basket +=b;

    basket = basket2;
    Basket basket3(basket2);
}
```

Comment: The destructor code doesn't require an explicit `if(m_fruits != nullptr)` test, since in C++ `delete[] nullptr;` is well-defined as being a no-op operation anyway.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner This is not the case for C++11 and onwards anymore. The standard states that "If the value of the operand of the delete-expression is not a null pointer value, the delete-expression will call a deallocation function (3.7.4.2). Otherwise, it is unspeciﬁed whether the deallocation function will be called." in  5.3.5/7.
Compiling witzh gcc address sanitizer also gives a "invalid free/delete" warning.

Comment: does that mean that C++11 breaks backwards compatibility with existing older C++ code in that respect?

Comment: Well, in this case it does not. Because §3.7.4.2/3 mentions "The value of the
first argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the deallocation
function is one supplied in the standard library, the call has no effect.". Since the delete[] used in this example is supplied by the stadnard library you can use it safely on a nullptr. But if the delete function is not supplied by the standard library, e.g.you are using your own memory management code (common practice for embedeed devices) it is UB.

Answer (score 0):

What if `m_fruits` is not empty here? I think it is a leak.

```
// SetEmpty
void Basket::setEmpty() {
  m_fruits = nullptr;
  m_cnt = 0;
  m_price = 0;
}
```

Comment: If i was to delete it it would cause more leaks, because some functions call it before writing

Comment: It wouldn't cause leaks, but rather undefined behavior.  (That said, it wouldn't be a bad idea to initialize your member-variables in a separate function that is only called at the top of your constructors, so that your `setEmpty()` command could then safely call `delete[] m_fruits; m_fruits = nullptr;`; that would allow you to keep your dealllocation code in just one place rather having 4-5 copies of it floating around, each of which has to be debugged and maintained separately)